# How (in)formal is the word "OK"?

Tags: formality

The word *OK* is pretty much everywhere, from simple conversations to user interfaces and even as a gesture:

That makes me wonder: how informal is the word "OK"? For instance, would it be appropriate in a legal document?

Comment: OK is not used in writing. It is speech. So, in legal writing, it would be fine for a quote but not otherwise.

Comment: @Lambie  But you just wrote it!

Comment: @stangdon Oh, I should go into the garden and eat worms because I didn't say it in a way that would be acceptable to Your Reverence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"OK" is **not** considered a formal word. It can be used sometimes in formal conversations, but not in writing. Some words you can use in its place are "acceptable", "all right", or "decent". It mostly depends on the context. If you look up synonyms for "OK", you can find a lot more ways to say it. There are a lot of informal synonyms. Some of the more informal ones that you should steer clear of are "cool", "hip", and "A-OK".

Comment: Pretty good answer, although I would say that 'alright' is not always considered correct, so in a formal written context I would definitely recommend 'all right' over it. Source http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/alright-vs-all-right

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know alright wasn't standard! I edited my answer, thanks!